# Typing fast on iPad selects words

Tags: keyboard, ipad

If I type fast on my iPad (using on screen, standard keyboard), I have noticed a weird behaviour: sometimes the word I am typing (or at times the entire sentence) becomes highlighted. The result is that, as I continue to type, I overwrite the selected text.

I must be pressing two (or more) keys at the same time for a brief moment possibly hitting a shortcut… but as it happens fast I’m never too sure of what I have pressed so can’t replicate it.

Has anyone experienced this? Am I pressing some key combinations/shortcuts I am not aware of?

It definitely makes my typing experience poor.